# copying the Launcher image into a file

Tags: clipboard

How would I copy the Launcher image, or any application window, so that I can paste it into an image application that saves to a file that can be inserted into an askubuntu.com question?  Which image application is available on a default installation of 12.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+PrntScr</kbd> to select the area to grab and copy to clipboard.

Or try [Screenshot](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/screen-shot-record.html).  To do so search for it in HUD:

[image]

and then choose your option, and click on Take Screenshot

[image]

Comment: or simply press "PrntScr"

Comment: Yes, you can, but the app will give you more options, and control.